# Delete button in every row in firebase web app

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display a list of data from my firebase and at the same time also insert a button for edit and delete to store their UID. I am on my day 2 and still haven't figure out how to store the uid on the button so that when I click the button it will get the uid of the said row. Can you please help me?

edited: code added

So here is the code for displaying it in a table:

```
     databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
               snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
               var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
               var childData = childSnapshot.val();

               var row = tblUsers.insertRow(rowIndex);
               var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
               var cellName = row.insertCell(1);
               cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childKey));

  cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.user_name));
               rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
                });
              });
```

I want to add a button that stores uid for deleting and editing .

Comment: Can you provide some code so people can understand what you are trying to do and help.

Comment: i edited it already sir. please check code thanks .